# Java file don't run in intellijIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[screenshot of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeiwX.png)

i am  absolute beginner. i have created a java file in IntellijIdea as shown in above pic. but it don't run. could anyone please tell me why.

Comment: you didn't put your code in your source directory. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: To me, it looks like you have a Java file called `Main.java`, and *that* file is being run.

Comment: You running the wrong file . you welcome to press on the green arrow from left side , and it will run you this code